# AttributeError: module 'six' has no attribute 'PY2' when running gcloud --version after gcloud components update

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk, gcloud-cli

I have trouble running `gcloud` commands after gcloud components update.

I'm using VS code Ubuntu 20.04. The error I get is:

```
ile "/home/user/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/encoding.py", line 41, in Encode
    if not six.PY2:
AttributeError: module 'six' has no attribute 'PY2'
```

I have installed six module.

I've installed six with:

`pip install six`

I've set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/bin/python3.10.

When executing Python3.10, and import six and `print(six.PY2)` everything works fine, and I don't get error. Only when executing `gcloud` commands.

What could be the reason for this?

The output of `pip show six`:

```
Name: six
Version: 1.16.0
Summary: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
Home-page: https://github.com/benjaminp/six
Author: Benjamin Peterson
Author-email: benjamin@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

Comment: What version of `six` did you install?

Comment: @JohnGordon 1.16.0

Comment: @JohnGordon this is the output of pip show six
`pip show six
Name: six
Version: 1.16.0
Summary: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
Home-page: https://github.com/benjaminp/six
Author: Benjamin Peterson
Author-email: benjamin@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages`

Comment: The Google Cloud CLI includes its own Python distribution. Why are you trying to modify that via `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON`?

Comment: @JohnHanley - If you already have Python that meets gcloud requirements, there isn't a need to install one from Google. Google supports this scenario via the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON env. I've always used it and never ran into any problems

Comment: @NoCommandLine - you are correct but you are experienced in Google Cloud. I do not recommend users modify the GCP CLI Python setup unless they know what they are doing with both the CLI and Python. My comment is to determine why the user is modifying the CLI environment. Just because you can does not mean you should.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've also tried to do it without setting CLOUDSDK_PYTHON, I get the same error.

Comment: @JohnHanley Do you have an idea how to debug this?

Comment: I would unset the environment variables, uninstall the Google Cloud CLI, reboot, and then install again. Verify that the CLI works from the command line correctly. Only at that point test with Visual Studio.  You will need the PATH environment setup correctly so that Visual Studio knows how to find the Google Cloud CLI, but you should not need to install any packages or fiddle with other environment variables.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you, i've did it and now it works!